# Capture video of running android application and then play it

Tags: android, video, screen, video-capture

I have developed one application in android and now I wish to add one more functionality in it. I want to capture the video of my application, means there will be one button and when user clicks on that button it starts recording each and everything which user do in the application. Let say user has press 2 buttons and play some sound, animations, etc. This all should be recorded and when user stop recording it gives options to play the video. I got this idea from the Talking Tom app available in android market.

Here is the link of that app.
[Talking tom](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.outfit7.talkingtom&hl=en)

See the screens, on the top of it the button of movie is there, which is used for recording whatever the user will do after pressing that button will be recorded and then play it, so it will play all the recorded things.

I want to do the same thing, if anyone is having any idea please kindly let me know.

Thnaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside recording a screencapture, you may can only record the users inputs in an file?
So every method the user calls will be recorded with a Timestamp in that file (or something like that). That can be done by the method itself, so all you have to do for playback is, calling your methods in the same order the user did. Games like StarCraft are recording userinputs and repeat them in playback mode. But your App has to produce excatly the same results with the same inputs, any variations in results will crash your playback.